# Upgrading Magento from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Magento to upgrade from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1

In the Magento Connect Manager, I had several packages that upgraded, including several that are now at 1.6.1 (Mage_Locale_en_US, Mage_Downloader and Lib_Mage),

But the site and admin still show (ver. 1.5.1.0). How do I upgrade fully to 1.6.1? I’ve tried flushing the cache of both the browser and of Magento.

What am I doing incorrectly, or missing?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.6 stable version has been released. Lots of fixes has been done in this major release. Then it’s the time you will need to upgrade your Magento website to the lastest version.

In this tutorial, i will show you how to upgrade Magento from 1.5.1.0 to 1.6.0 via command line.

```
chmod 700 ./mage

./mage mage-setup .
./mage install community Mage_Downloader –force
./mage install community Mage_All_Latest –force

chmod 700 ./mage

./mage sync-pear
./mage list-installed
./mage list-upgrades
./mage install Mage_All_Latest –force

chmod 700 ./mage

./mage config-set preferred_state beta
./mage list-installed
./mage list-upgrades
```

Note:

At any step, if you get the error message “bash: ./mage: Permission denied”, please try to use this command from command line again:

```
chmod 700 ./mage
```

After doing all above steps, remember to clear all caches:

```
rm -rf /var/cache session
```

and reindex all tables:

```
./shell php indexer.php reindexall
```

After clearing all caches and reindexing all tables, if you get some error messages about data integration among tables like:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:268:”Error in file: “/path_to_the_root_folder/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/sql/eav_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php” – SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of ‘./your_database/customer_entity_text’ to ‘./your_database/#sql2-5ef-3a9′ (errno: 152)”;i:1;s:1080:”#0 /path_to_the_root_folder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception(‘Mage_Core’, ‘Error in file: …’)
a:5:{i:0;s:268:”Error in file: “/path_to_the_root_folder/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/sql/eav_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php” – SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of ‘./your_database/customer_entity_text’ to ‘./dev_migento/#sql2-5ef-3a9′ (errno: 152)”;i:1;s:1080:”#0 /path_to_the_root_folder /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception(‘Mage_Core’, ‘Error in file: …’)
```

Please open the /app/etc/config.xml file and change the initStatements note from

```
<initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
```

to

```
 <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;</initStatements>
```

Try this you will get the result.

Comment: It seems you just copied and pasted the expertmagentodevelopers web site.

Sadly, I think that article is slightly outdated, as I got multiple errors, including:

Error: channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist!

Error: install: Package community/Mage_Downloader failed: Version for 'Mage_Downloader' was not detected